возникшая проблема привела к прекращению работы программы
У меня в программе Godot с недавнего времени, когда я захожу в программу, начинаю что то делать, все нормально работает, и в какой то момент, когда я даже ничего не делаю, у меня программа просто вырубаеться и мне выдает
"возникшая проблема привела к прекращению работы программы"

Я смотрел Диспетчер задач и там вроде компьютер не нагружен.
До этого все было абсолютно нормально.

Windows 7 давно никем не поддерживается, документация Godot давно рекомендует хотя бы Windows 10

Я использую версию 3.5


Проверьте лог-файлы Godot 2. Откройте "Просмотр событий" (Event Viewer) и посмотрите в разделах "Журналы Windows -> Приложение" и "Журналы Windows -> Система" на наличие ошибок, связанных с Godot

